# perl index skips search value

Tags: string, perl, debugging

I am writing a program that is heavily dependent on the perl's index function to take strings. My objective so to break this string into a series of substrings that do not have any spaces.

The problem that I am having is that in the second half of the loop the index function starts skipping spaces.

I am using the test data:

> 1 12 a 2 5 P Q

I am expecting to get:

> 1, 12, a, 2, 5, P, Q,

Instead I get:

> 1, 12, a, 2 5, P Q,

My code follows:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ivalue = <stdin>;
chomp($ivalue);
$ivalue = $ivalue . " ";
my $current;
my $space = 0;
my $safespace = 0;
my $lastspace = 0;
my $closestspace = 0;
my $i = 0;
# Test data - 1 12 a 2 5 P Q
while ($space != -1){
  $space = index($ivalue, " ", $space + $i++);
  $closestspace = $space - $lastspace;                      
  #print $lastspace . " " . $space . " = " . $closestspace . "; ";
  $current = substr($ivalue, $lastspace, $closestspace);
  #say "substring = " . $current;
  $lastspace = $space + 1;
}
```

Thanks ahead of time! If anyone has any suggestion on how to improve the way I asked my question or on my code in general those are appreciated as well.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, `index` and `substr` are almost certainly the wrong tools for the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`$space = index($ivalue, " ", $space + $i++);`

instead of using `$i`, make that `$space + 1`